# Selenium webdriver wait element and click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
InternetExplorerDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.get("http://www.wiki-doctor.com");
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
               .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnSearch")));
element.click();
```

it waits for the element btnSearch to be displayed and click on it, however, it doesn' t seems to do anything, do you have any idea why it happens ?

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? When I run your code using chrome, I get an alert saying "Please insert address".

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer

Comment: String service = "C:\\ToolsQA\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.7.0\\IEDriverServer.exe";
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", service);
  InternetExplorerDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adds United States as a locale, and then waits until a picture of the doctor is displayed.

```
driver.get("http://www.wiki-doctor.com");
//Enter united states into field
driver.findElement(By.id("field-findDoctor-town")).sendKeys("United States");
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
               .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnSearch")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
//Wait for picture of doctor
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#dvparcticianlist > div.row > div > div.listing-row > div.doc-photo-container")));
       System.out.println("Search Successful");
   }
```

Comment: hi, Reezo, a question regarding the argument[0], wha' s that ? where is this object coming from ? cheers

Comment: Check the definition from Selenium ExecuteScript page

The arguments will be made available to the JavaScript via the "arguments" magic variable, as if the function were called via "Function.apply"

and the returning value of executeScript is:

Returns: One of Boolean, Long, String, List or WebElement. Or null.

which means that returning object is a list and you can interact with by arguments[0] magic variable.

Answer (score 1):

Once the page is loaded, first we need to `wait` for the intended `WebElement` i.e. the first `Search Box` to be clickable. Then we will send some text to both the `Search Boxes` and then invoke `click()` method on the `Search Button` as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://www.wiki-doctor.com");
WebElement locality = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
       .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='field-findDoctor-town']")));
locality.sendKeys("Pune");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='speciality']")).sendKeys("Doctor");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btnSearch']")).click();
```

Comment: I tried your code and still nothing happens, even the searchbox is not filled, it' s like the ids are never found

Comment: I think there is something to do with my internet explorer version and the download driver, as the codes works pretty well in chrome

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status

Answer (score -1):

```
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath")));     
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
```

Comment: Please make an effort to explain your answer.